# Geometry problem about perpendicular segments

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> As shown in the graph below, $D\in AB,E\in AC,DB=BC=CE$. Let $F=BE\cap CD$, the two arcs pathing through $ADC$ and $AEB$ intersect at $G$. Show that $FG\bot BC$.

First, I proved two sets of $4$ concyclic points.

$\because \angle FBG=\angle EBG=\angle EAG=\angle CAG=\angle CDG=\angle FDG$

$\therefore BDFG$ concyclic. Similarly, $EFGC$ concyclic.

Now the property of three segments being equal hasn't been used yet, and that maybe produces more properties with the angles. Also $G$ appears to be the orthocenter of $\triangle BCF$. So perhaps te problem could be solved by angles purely.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already shown that $BDFG$ and $CEFG$ are cyclic quadrilaterals.

Note that,

$\angle BGF = 180^ - \angle BCF$
$\angle CGF = 180^\circ - \angle CBF$

As angle subtended at $G$ by two of the sides of $\triangle BCF$ is supplement of angle formed at corresponding vertex, $G$ must be orthocenter of $\triangle BCF$ and hence $FG \perp BC$.

---

As sum of three angles formed at $G$ is $360^\circ$, you could also show that

$\angle BGC = 360^\circ - (180^\circ - \angle BCF) - (180^\circ - \angle CBF)$

i.e. $\angle BGC = 180^\circ - \angle BFC$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you see on figure $O_1B$ is perpendicular bisector of DC so it is coincident on altitude from B of isosceles triangle DBC. Similarly $O_2 C$ is coincident on altitude from C of isosceles triangle BCE. So G is intersection of the altitudes of triangle FBC, this means G is orthocenter of triangle FBC and FG is a part of altitude FH so it is perpendicular on BC.